# Toolbar logo and title are centered even though they're not supposed to be

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm having trouble implementing a Toolbar in my Android application. I have several problems, really.

First off, here's my **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_Main);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_actions);

        setActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

    <Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_Main"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary" />

    <!-- There's an EditText here, but I think that's not the problem -->

</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The problems I'm having are:

1. the menu is gone;
2. the logo and title text are centered in the Toolbar, even though I'm pretty sure I haven't set any property to center or whatever.

Now the first problem I can fix by removing the `setActionBar` part (not sure if that's good practice though), but second one, not so much. The logo and text remain centered no matter what I try. I've tried setting the Toolbar's gravity to `top|left`, as well as some other things, all to no avail.

When searching on Google (or StackOverflow), all I get are results asking to center the text, which is what I *don't* want.

I should also mention that I'm developing the app only for API level 21, so no AppCompat and all that fancy stuff, just a Toolbar that I wish to use as the app's main ActionBar.

I'm probably just missing some tiny thing, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to set toolbar icon and title in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

To me:

- You should *not* remove the `setActionBar()` call;
- Your menu might be disappearing because maybe you have a hardware menu button on your device. Try tapping and see what happens. To fix however, try deleting the `inflateMenu()` line and inflate the menu during `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, as usual;
- Title and logo issues, as well as menu disappearing, might be due to:

  ```
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
  ```

  Why these lines? Just remove them if you don't need.
- If this doesn't fix, try calling `setActionBar(toolbar)` first, and *then* set title using `getActionBar().setTitle()` . However I'm pretty sure that removing the two window lines from your style will be enough, so do that first.

Comment: Android Studio throws an error if I remove the `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>`, so those need to be left in. "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set android:windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead." Any idea what could be the problem? Also, doing the things you suggested don't have any effect, the icon/logo and title are still centered.

Comment: To avoid the error, inherit from `parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"`. Let me know what stays wrong then (menu, gravity).

Comment: The logo and title are still centered, so it doesn't work. The menu is fully working.

Comment: Have you tried calling `setActionBar()` before setting logo&title on the toolbar, and/or setting logo&title via `getActionBar().setTitle()` & `getActionBar().setLogo()`  ?

Comment: Yes, I've used `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_Main); setActionBar(toolbar); getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo); getActionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);`. Still gives me the centered logo/text.

Comment: If you posted all the relevant code, I would say that's weird. There are lots of question here on how to *have* centered title and logo :)

Comment: Very strange indeed. Any idea what I should do? My guess would be just go back to a standard ActionBar, but I'd prefer the Toolbar solution as that gives more control.

Comment: I would double check SDK version, upgrade build tools + IDE + gradle stuff, and start from scratch with a new project.